COUNTIF excel formula // multiple conditions
Trying to find a sort of COUNTIF excel formula which can count the number of publications based on a date (i.e. all published in 2023), as well as by publisher. In this example I would for instance want a formula which returns the number of books published in 2023 by Book Inc, i.e. 4 books.
enter image description here

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Use SUMPRODUCT() or SUM() --> =SUMPRODUCT((B2:B100="Book Inc")*(YEAR(C2:H100)=2023)) increase the range as per your suit
